# How to change the permission level, download file

Tags: c#, winforms, url, browser, download

I try to create a web browser. Currently I try to realize a function that if the user wants to download some file an additional window is shown with a list of already downloaded files. If the file has already been loaded, a message is shown (just an idea).

So far, I get a link to the file location in the main form and send it to the other form:

```
DownLoadFile dlf = new DownLoadFile();
...
        WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
        wb.Navigating += new WebBrowserNavigatingEventHandler(wb_Navigating);
...
    private void wb_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
    {
...
        if (e.Url.ToString().EndsWith(".mp3"))
        {
            dlf.DownloadPath = e.Url;
            dlf.Show();
        }
    }
```

In the new form I try to use this link for file downloading:

```
public Uri DownloadPath { get; set; }
...

private void DownLoadFile_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filePath = null;

        //get FileName from URL 
        string[] ArrayForName;
        ArrayForName = DownloadPath.ToString().Split('/');
        saveFileDialogFile.FileName = 
            ArrayForName[ArrayForName.Length-1].Replace("%"," ").Trim();

        if (saveFileDialogFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            //get Url
            Uri url = new Uri(DownloadPath.ToString());     
            //get place where want to save with default name
            filePath = saveFileDialogFile.FileName;
            //event for result
            client.DownloadFileCompleted += 
                new System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventHandler (client_DownloadFileCompleted);
            //download
            client.DownloadFileAsync(url, filePath);
        }
    }

    void client_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Compleated");
    }
```

My questions are:

1. Regarding `if (e.Url.ToString().EndsWith(".mp3"))` - How can i
   change this for knowing not only when the user tries to download mp3 file,
   but all types of files - maybe there is a better way
2. If i want to download a file using some link directly, I get the message "Currently you have not required permission for that" - How can I
   change permission level for my web browser
3. If i finally get a link to the file and start to download it, as result just name of file (size of file 0 kb) - where i'm wrong.

Comment: Have you unit tested the construction of the url?

Comment: No, can you give some samples with URL testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my solution (maybe not the best one)

create event for webBrowser

```
wb.Navigating += new WebBrowserNavigatingEventHandler(wb_Navigating);
```

and in this event use next

```
        if (GetWorkingWebBrowser().StatusText != null)
        {
            try
            {
                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(GetWorkingWebBrowser().StatusText);
                request.Method = "HEAD";

                using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
                {
                    if (response.ContentLength > 0 && 
                         !response.ContentType.ToString().ToLower().Contains("text/html"))
                    {
                        dlf.DownloadPath = e.Url; //move url to my form for dwnload
                        dlf.Show(); //show form
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (UriFormatException)
            {
            }
            catch (WebException)
            {
            }
        }
```

`GetWorkingWebBrowser()` - method that return current active webBrowser on tab, meas `webBrowser`